# elementary programs crash when opening context menus

Tags: release-freya

After trying out kde (`kubuntu-desktop`) on my elementary OS Frey installation, I uninstalled KDE again and went back to pantheon.

Now, whenever I open a context menu in one of the elementary apps, the app crashes. It works fine in pidgin, firefox, etc. Also, other users on the same system (tried the guest account) are not affected.

How would I begin to debug this?

Running the app from a terminal with `-d` enabled just segfaults.

From dmesg:

```
[17917.893949] pantheon-termin[12168]: segfault at 0 ip           (null) sp 00007ffed8c28e68 error 14 in pantheon-terminal[400000+29000]
```